# Android Runnable and handler on main UI Thread

Tags: java, android, thread-safety, runnable

Regarding Java Andriod Handlers:

```
handler.post(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

From what i understand this gets run on the whatever thread the handler was instantiated on.  so lets say in Android i instantiate the handler on the main thread, my question then is what is the point of the runnable ? your adding a task to the messaging queue of the main UI thread, why not just skip the runnable and create a  method since your on the main thread already.  I've seen programmers doing this and i want to know why ?

I understand we can do `Thread genThread = new Thread(new myRunnable());` but i want to know if there is any value of a Runnable on the main thread.

Comment: handler.post can be called from any thread, even if it was instantiated on the ui thread.

Comment: You're far better off, resource and performance wise, using handler.obtainMessage() and .sendMessage than dynamically creating a new runnable each time.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you want to run some code but you don't want it to run immediately, you want to defer it. One of the most common uses for this in my experience is when you are in the layout phase and you want to "queue" up something to happen once the layout phase is done. For this you simply post a Runnable to the UI thread's message queue and it will get put at the end of the message queue...which is exactly where you want it.

Another common use case is if you want to find out the size of a view from onCreate. In onCreate the view hasn't been measured yet so this won't work:

```
Log.d(TAG, view.getWidth());
```

Instead you can do this:

```
view.post(new Runnable() {public void run() {Log.d(TAG, view.getWidth());}}) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using **AsyncTask<>** rather than **Handlers** as they are easier to understand and make for cleaner code. I know that I am diverting from the original question posted but this is just a suggestion. If you want to know more about AsyncTask<> below is the link.

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)